# Access and write back to txt file on linux server from iOS on local network

Tags: ios, linux, ssh

I currently have a txt file on a Linux install that I need to access from my app and write back to. The app and the Linux server are on the same subnet and I have full control of both machines (permissions). I've thought about SSHing into the machine but this obviously has its security drawbacks sending raw credentials. Does anyone have any suggestions on what framework to use to create a secure tunnel or perhaps an alternative solution?

Comment: What do you mean "sending raw credentials"? SSH doesn't send passwords in cleartext. Or do you mean hardcoding into the app? *Any* way your app can access your server, a user with access to the app can figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple web service in your language of choice php, python, ruby, etc. And make a simple secure call to your service with the changes.